# Отправка POST с помощью checkBox

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Отправляю POST с помощью checkBoxa.

```
$checked;
if(isset($_POST['likeBox'])){
    echo "true";
    $checked = "checked";
}else{
    $checked = "";
}
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"likeBox\"  class=\"like\" $checked >";
```

Место, где отображается checkBox:

```
<form action="add_to_base.php" method="post" class="now_playing"></form>
```

Можно ли каким-то таким образом это сделать? Или нужно использовать ajax?

Comment: Вы хотите отправить форму на сервер используя вместо кнопки `submit` чекбокс? Или что?

Comment: Мне просто нужно узнать состояние чекбокса.

Comment: Выведите `$_POST`, посмотрите, какой там формат у значений, все встанет на свои места.